# function that gets field value- JS

Tags: javascript, crm

I want to write function that gets field value and pit it on *global JS file* so that I can use it instead of writing this all the time:

```
var regarding = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue;// example
```

Can anyone help me how to write it and how to use it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you declare the above code in the window scope you can use `regarding` everywhere.

Comment: @A1rPun Actually, there is something missing. The above will retain a reference to the `getValue()` function, but lose the context for the respective node. So you would have to either create a new function for this or use `bind()` to retain context.

Answer (score 0):

You "can" declare it as global var

**Example**

```
window.regarding = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue;
```

If you want the function as you described.

```
window.regarding = function() {
   return Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue;
}
```

The value of `window.regarding` is accessible everywhere in js scope.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ment that i want to do this on alot of fields.. the regarding  was an example. how can i write this?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

You can write a javascript like this:

```
function GetValueField(fieldName)
{
    if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName) == undefined)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).getValue();
}
```

If write this and you add it in a shared library like common.js, you can access to this function in every javascript you have for that form.

So if I am in entityfunction.js I can call `var regarding = GetValueField("regardingobjectid")`

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, if you need more details just tell me.